# remove xmr.crypto-pool.fr process ubuntu

Tags: security, server, ubuntu-14.04, malware

there been an anonymous process running on my Ubuntu server, which is utilizing 100% memory.

User: Tomcat

process : /tmp/autox -B -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.crypto-pool.fr:443 -u 47TS1NQvebb3Feq91MqKdSGCUq18dTEdmfTTrRSGFFC2fK85NRdABwUasUA8EUaiuLiGa6wYtv5aoR8BmjYsDmTx9DQbfRX -p x

I keep trying to kill the process and file which I found in /tmp folder but still, it recreates the file with different name and starts the process back.

i Drop INPUT & OUTPUT for xmr.crypto-pool.fr in IPTABLES

now It has been an irritating on the server.

guys please help !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is hacked or infected with a Miner malware (Malware which uses your system to mine Crypto Currency [Monero, in this case]).

Look for any suspicious process/Cronjob.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129448/how-can-i-kill-minerd-malware-on-an-aws-ec2-instance

Comment: I went through this article but was no help except for using iptable drop,
other than that no use

Answer (score 0):

I just realized today that my server was infected as well. The process for me wasn't /tmp/autox but an instance of ./http.conf (not the ./ in the beginning). When looking at the crons i found this one:

```
* * * * * /tmp/.-/update >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I then deleted the line from my crons and went to `/tmp/.-/` where the malware is indeed siting. 
As a temporary fix i added an `exit` statement at the top of each script found in that folder. I don't want to it delete just yet as I want to investigate a bit more.
I also deleted all the key added in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. 
Now when killing the process it doesn't start again.

I'll update my answer if I find anything else.

Comment: thx for replying back, but in my case, there is no cronjob for running those process, 
I don't know from where this is executing and after deleting recreating file